# Custom category image size in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working on a custom category page in WooCommerce and I am struggling to find a way to specify a custom image size.

I note you can set a site wide image size but I only wish to apply the size to this code specifically.

The code I am using to get the image is:

```
<?php
    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true ); // Get Category Thumbnail
    $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
    if ( $image ) {
        echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="" />';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this out,

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail' );
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $cat->term_id, array( 100, 100) ); // Other resolutions
```

use the category id in this function to return the image of the category and you can set your custom width and height of the image inside that.

Thank you.